# how to import custom fabric folder

Tags: python, django, fabric

I have this script, that i use to log in on many servers through ssh and it was running ok on python2

```
/user/local/bin/a

#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import os
import sys
sys.path.append("fabric_/")

import fabfile

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('Usage: a <host>')
    sys.exit(-1)

os.system('ssh root@{}'.format(fabfile.env.roledefs[sys.argv[1]][0]))
```

but, now with python3, when i try to run the command("a client") it gives me a error

[image: error when running the command a client]

the correct fabfile that has the "env" is on my project folder `ruicadete/fabric_/fabfile.py`

i already tried to make sys.path only with the right fabfile, it worked but the it doesn't find the modules i've imported on the fabfile.

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i've found was to add the fabfile on top of other sys.path path's.

Something like that

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/rc/code/ruicadete/fabric_/', # added path to fabfile that i want
    '/usr/local/bin',
    '/home/rc/.virtualenvs/pam/lib/python37.zip',
    '/home/rc/.virtualenvs/pam/lib/python3.7',
    '/home/rc/.virtualenvs/pam/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/var/opt/python37/lib/python3.7',
    '/home/rc/.virtualenvs/pam/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/home/rc/.virtualenvs/pam/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/home/rc/.virtualenvs/pam/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
    '/home/rc/.ipython',
]
```